# How to Use Versioning & BundleConfig.cs together

Tags: javascript, css, versioning, bundling-and-minification

I have issues where if I make a change to a CSS or javascript file and then push it to production, the change does not get picked up by client browsers unless they do a ctrl+F5 refresh. I work in a school system with thousands of users so it's not practical for them to know to do this -- or when a change has been made to do it.

I've been reading up and the consensus seems to be to ad a "java.js?v=1.0" to the end of the file. My website uses bundling, and I don't think I'm doing something right. When I try to put this to the end of the files in the .cs config file, when I push it out my site does not recognize the references files at all any more.

For example, he's a list of files that I'm bundling:

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/utilitiesJs").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.dynatable.js",
            "~/Scripts/js-cookie.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap-toolkit.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/common.js?v=1.0",
            "~/Scripts/dropdown.js?v=1.0",
            "~/Scripts/waitingFor.js",
            "~/Scripts/analytics.js"));
```

As you can see I added the "V=1.0" onto the end of common.js and dropdown.js.  When I go out to the webstie and view the Page Source, these files are simply missing from the includes:

```
<script src="/DMC/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/DMC/Scripts/jquery.dynatable.js"></script>
<script src="/DMC/Scripts/js-cookie.js"></script>
<script src="/DMC/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/DMC/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script src="/DMC/Scripts/bootstrap-toolkit.min.js"></script>
<script src="/DMC/Scripts/waitingFor.js"></script>
<script src="/DMC/Scripts/analytics.js"></script>
```

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Do I need to also rename the common and dropdown files or something?  I currently have them named simply as common.js and dropdown.js.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: UPDATE: What I ended up doing was following the more standard conventions -- I renamed the file to common-1.0.js, and am referencing that specific name in the bundle.  Going forward, any time I make a change to the js file I'll just bump up the version number and remember to go into the bundle and update the version there as well.

Answer (score 0):

If might not be as efficient but have you tried disabling caching at the page level or possibly setting a smaller cache window?

Also, if the browsers and server support it, your controlled environment makes HTTP/2 a real possibility.  Things like bundling become a non-problem.